# How to find out the Active Record migration version?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How to find out the migration version (timestamp) from within Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.1.1/ActiveRecord/Migrator#current_version-class_method) method

```
ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version
   (154.0ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` 
=> 20141218151812
```